# Why is my "Divide by Zero" prevention not working?

Tags: c#

I've been working on a calculator using C# and came across an issue I haven't been able to work past.

Currently when a user enters a number divided by zero then the answer defaults to 0.00 when instead it should be invalid.

I have no idea why and after tinkering with it for awhile I haven't been able to figure it out. Here is the relevant code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
                double number1, number2, ans; // Identify variables as double to account for decimals.
                number1 = Convert.ToDouble(num1.Text); // Convert the contents of the textBox into a double.
                number2 = Convert.ToDouble(num2.Text); // 
                ans = 0.0;
                string symbol = modifier1.Text;

                if (symbol == "/" && number2 == 0) // This part seems to be broken.
                    answer.Text = "Invalid input.";
                else
                    if (symbol == "+")
                        ans = number1 + number2;
                    else if (symbol == "-")
                        ans = number1 - number2;
                    else if (symbol == "/")
                        ans = number1 / number2;
                    else if (symbol == "*")
                        ans = number1 * number2;
                    else
                        ans = 0;

                    answer.Text = ans.ToString("n"); // Change label value to a number.
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this? It seems pretty straight forward but I'm missing something.

Comment: You missing `return` or curly braces. Please use debugger to confirm. Also make sure you are clear on rules of language you are using - C# *does not* use significant whitespace unlike some other languages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change this :

```
if (symbol == "/" && number2 == 0) // This part seems to be broken.
                answer.Text = "Invalid input.";
```

To :

```
if (symbol == "/" && number2 == 0) { answer.Text = "Invalid input."; return; }
```

*Explanation:*
The condition in 'if' clause in your code is correct. And it does what is expected - it changes answer.Text property to "Invalid input" however a bit later it is changed again on this line :

```
answer.Text = ans.ToString("n"); // Change label value to a number.
```

And because your condition in 'if' clause returned true - 'else' block was not executed. That's why you see 0.00 (default value of type double).

P.S.
So by adding `return` statement to if clause you just basically end your method.
It is like if you say to compiler *"Hey *if* this guy is trying to `divide by zero` alert him 'Ivalid input' and do nothing, return from method".*

Other way to sort it out would be to :

```
if (divide by zero attempt) { your code here } else
{
    and place rest of your method code here
}
```

But I would not recommend this because it uses redundant else statement and {} figures. You can avoid all of it by using if() {....; return; } in your case.

You may also benefit from using `switch` block and your code might be refactored to something like :

```
double number1, number2, ans; // Identify variables as double to account for decimals.
number1 = Convert.ToDouble(num1.Text); // Convert the contents of the textBox into a double.
number2 = Convert.ToDouble(num2.Text); // 
ans = 0.0;
string symbol = modifier1.Text;

if (symbol == "/" && number2 == 0) { answer.Text = "Invalid input."; return;}
switch(symbol)
{
   case "+": ans = number1 + number2; break;
   case "-": ans = number1 - number2; break;
   case "*": ans = number1 * number2; break;
   case "/": ans = number1 / number2; break;
   default : answer.Text = "Invalid sign."; return;
}                

answer.Text = ans.ToString("n"); // Change label value to a number.
```

Comment: @Sayse Thank you. I explained it in my answer update.

Comment: @DavidArno Else statement in op code is correct because it has only ONE if clause and nothing more. Like this : else if (symbol == "+") // some code // else if  and so on. Check my answer update it explains it all.

Answer (score 5):

To help you understand what's gone wrong, it helps to lay the code out as the compiler sees it, rather than how you imagine it's working:

```
double number1, number2, ans; // Identify variables as double to account for decimals.
number1 = Convert.ToDouble(num1.Text); // Convert the contents of the textBox into a double.
number2 = Convert.ToDouble(num2.Text); // 
ans = 0.0;
string symbol = modifier1.Text;

if (symbol == "/" && number2 == 0) // This part seems to be broken.
    answer.Text = "Invalid input.";
else if (symbol == "+")
    ans = number1 + number2;
else if (symbol == "-")
    ans = number1 - number2;
else if (symbol == "/")
    ans = number1 / number2;
else if (symbol == "*")
    ans = number1 * number2;
else
    ans = 0;

answer.Text = ans.ToString("n"); // Change label value to a number.
```

So when the divide by zero situation occurs, first `answer.Text` is set to "Invalid input.", then the control flow drops to the last line and it's overwritten with `0.0`.

The neatly highlights why it's really important to use `{}` even for single statements. Do that and the code will work as you expect:

```
double number1, number2, ans; // Identify variables as double to account for decimals.
number1 = Convert.ToDouble(num1.Text); // Convert the contents of the textBox into a double.
number2 = Convert.ToDouble(num2.Text); // 
ans = 0.0;
string symbol = modifier1.Text;

if (symbol == "/" && number2 == 0) // This part seems to be broken.
{
    answer.Text = "Invalid input.";
}
else 
{
    if (symbol == "+")
    {
        ans = number1 + number2;
    }
    else if (symbol == "-")
    {
        ans = number1 - number2;
    }
    else if (symbol == "/")
    {
        ans = number1 / number2;
    }
    else if (symbol == "*")
    {
        ans = number1 * number2;
    }
    else
    {
        ans = 0;
    }

    answer.Text = ans.ToString("n"); // Change label value to a number.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

check here for basics of if else condition in C#
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx